# Joining two tables with a queried table

Tags: sql, mysql

Oh great SQL gods I require your assistance.

Here is my Schema:

```
CAR(Serial_no,Model,Manufacturer,Price)
OPTIONS(Serial_no,Option_name,Price)
SALE(Salesperson_id,Serial_no,Date,Sale_price)
SALESPERSON(Salesperson_id,Name,Phone)
```

1. First, I need to join the CAR and SALE table by Serial_no.
2. Second, i need to take the OPTIONS table and SUM all the prices for similar Serial_no which the following does:

   SELECT O.Serial_no, SUM(O.Price)
       FROM OPTIONS O
       GROUP BY (O.Serial_no);
3. Last I need to merge steps one and two and query the result so I get a resulting set of where CAR.Price < (SALE.Sale_price + OPTIONS.Price).

Can this be done? Any help would be immensely appreciated!

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: Hi, I've tried this so farSELECT C.Serial_no, C.Price, S.Sale_price, SUM(O.Price) AS Cost
 FROM (CAR C, SALE S) LEFT OUTER JOIN OPTIONS O
  ON C.Serial_no = O.Serial_no
 WHERE C.Serial_no = S.Serial_no AND C.Price < (S.Sale_price)
 GROUP BY (C.Serial_no); But it doesn't allow me to to add the O.Cost to S.Sale_price

Comment: Is there a single sale only for each car?

Comment: There are multiple entries per each serial number in options. There seems to be the tricky part because I must add up prices for similar Serial_no

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT C.Serial_no,
  MIN(c.Price) CarPrice,
  MIN(s.Sale_price) SalePrice,
  SUM(o.Price) OptionsPrice,
  MIN(s.Sale_price) + IFNULL(SUM(o.Price),0) TotalPrice
FROM Car c JOIN Sale s ON c.Serial_no = s.Serial_no
  LEFT JOIN `Options` o ON c.Serial_no = o.Serial_no
GROUP BY c.Serial_no
HAVING MIN(c.Price) < MIN(s.Sale_price) + IFNULL(SUM(o.Price),0)
```

Note: the `MIN()` are not taking anything away, it is only there since you are grouping, and the options table may have multiple rows.

Another option would be to do the calculations in a Subquery which may lead to better performance:

```
SELECT C.Serial_no,
  C.Price,
  S.Sale_price,
  og.SumPrice
FROM Car c JOIN Sale s ON c.Serial_no = s.Serial_no
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT Serial_no, SUM(Price) SumPrice
    FROM `Options`
    GROUP BY Serial_no
  ) og ON c.Serial_no = og.Serial_no
WHERE c.Price < s.Sale_price + IFNULL(og.SumPrice,0)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be compiling for me :( SELECT C.Serial_no, MIN(C.Price), SUM(O.Price)
FROM CAR C JOIN SALE S USING(Serial_no)
  LEFT JOIN OPTIONS O ON USING(Serial_no)
GROUP BY C.Serial_no
HAVING MIN(C.Price) < MIN(S.Sale_price) + SUM(O.Price);

Comment: @mark-anderson Updated query. What error messages are you getting?

Comment: I think it's the alias inconsistency. You've aliased the subquery as `o` and are referencing it once as `o` and twice as `og`.